(kdb+/q) Table schema definitions
I have a question about table schemas in kdb+
How do you define a list of floats in a table schema?
I understand that price:float$() works for type f but what about for F

Any complex list is defined using ().
meta  checks only the first few rows to give capital letter types such as F. In truth the column could have other types as well. select distinct type each mycol from tab is how you can check and confirm the whole column is consistent.
